# How to fix Gradle error when change SDK version 26 to 28

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm tried to upgrade the SDK version 26 to 28 , but Gradle shows error . How can i resolve this error

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Above dependency shows error 
[image: error image]

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 10
    versionName '1.5'
}
```

[Build Error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kJSl.jpg)

Comment: Try to convert your project to androidX . But  post your logcat, so we can better help solve this issue

Comment: you have to show full Gradle file. It seems version mismatch error so we need full Gradle file.

Comment: you have to add `buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"` after `compileSdkVersion 28` in build.gradle file

Comment: Added buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" , but when i sync the gradle file still showing error. Please go through my Build error report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error clearly mentioned that you are using two version of support library 28.0.0 and 26.1.0. Please make all 28.0.0. Hope this solve your problem.

Also you are using some library that are already migrated to AndroidX. To use this you also have to migrate your project to androidX. Try 
**Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**

And press DoRefactor

Comment: Still it shows error, please check my build error report

Comment: You are using some library that are already migrated to AndroidX. To use this you also have to migrate your project to androidX. Try **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**

Comment: yeah.. Error gone , but is there any problem if we migrate it to android X.?

Comment: What kind of problem? AndroidX is the future as google remove support library from API 29

Comment: @AswinTP, Are your problems solved or having more issues?

Comment: If this solve your problem then accept the answer and upvote so that other can find it useful. Thanks